# Помогите с файловым менеджером на C# Cosmos

Tags: c#, .net, файлы, файловая-система, ос

Пытался значит я написать файловый менеджер для своей осочки, но как обычно с файлами в c# - что-то и поломается. Особенно я не понимаю почему при вводе пути к папке можно ввести абсолютно любое значение, даже: "ahdjkabjkwej". Прошу помочь мне с моим кодом:

````
            Sys.FileSystem.VFS.VFSManager.RegisterVFS(fs);
            Console.WriteLine("FileManager I (c) AlphaSoftware 2022");
            Console.WriteLine("Write 'help' to perfomance commands");
            string path = @"C:\Files\";
            while (true)
            {
                Console.Write(path + ": ");
                string input = Console.ReadLine();
                if (input == "help")
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Perfomance commands");
                    Console.WriteLine("Directories:");
                    Console.WriteLine("'chgdir' - Change directory");
                    Console.WriteLine("'crtdir' - Create directory");
                    Console.WriteLine("'deldir' - Delete directory");
                    Console.WriteLine();
                    Console.WriteLine("Files:");
                    Console.WriteLine("'opnfil' - Open file");
                    Console.WriteLine("'crtfil' - Create file");
                    Console.WriteLine("'delfil' - Delete file");
                }
                if (input == "chgdir")
                {
                    Console.Write("Path: ");
                    string newpath = Console.ReadLine();
                    if (!Directory.Exists(@"" + newpath))
                    {
                        path = newpath;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Path not found!");
                    }
                }
                if (input == "crtdir")
                {
                    Console.Write("Path (with new dir): ");
                    string newpath = Console.ReadLine();
                    if (!Directory.Exists(@"" + newpath))
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Path found! Nothing has changed");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        fs.CreateDirectory(@"" + newpath);
                        path = newpath;
                    }
                }
                if (input == "deldir")
                { 
                    Console.WriteLine("Module not loaded!");
                }
                if (input == "crtfil")
                {
                    Console.Write("Path (with new file): ");
                    string newpath = Console.ReadLine();
                    if (!Directory.Exists(@"" + newpath))
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Path found! Nothing has changed");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        fs.CreateFile(@"" + newpath);
                        path = newpath;
                    }
                }
                if (input == "delfil")
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Module not loaded!");
                }
            }
        }```
````

Comment: Боюсь, проблема здесь вовсе не в System.IO

Comment: Вам бы освоить конструкцию `switch-case`.

Comment: `if (!Directory.Exists(...))` читается как "если католог не существует". В этом проблема? Уберите `!` там где не надо отрицание.

Comment: скорее всего, попробую